# every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.8, mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, pubspec

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
name: my_chat_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  chat:
    path: ./chat
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^4.1.4
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
```

**chat/pubspec.yaml:**

```
name: chat
description: A new Flutter package project.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rethinkdb_dart: ^2.3.2+6
  encrypt: ^4.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:
```

**flutter pub get output in pubspec.yaml:**

Running "flutter pub get" in my_chat_app...
Because mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 depends on test_api ^0.2.19-nullsafety and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.8, mockito >=4.1.2 <=5.0.0-nullsafety.7 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because my_chat_app depends on both flutter_test from sdk and mockito ^4.1.4, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because my_chat_app depends on both flutter_test from sdk and mockito ^4.1.4, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade the mockito version?

Comment: I have this same issue, did you figure anything out? @restless226

Comment: @CbL I'm following a tutorial that has the same code & same issue. I upgrade Mockito and still run into tons of issues. Because the code is from before null safety. Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: @JohnBradens For this case, you can only either use the older mockito version (<= 4.1.4) or upgrade whole project to null-safety.

Comment: @CbL thanks for answering. I'd like to upgrade to null safety in the future, but for now I'd like to just get the old/current non-nullsafe version working if possible. If I leave the older version of mockito, how can I resolve the flutter test incompatibility error?

Comment: @JohnBradens You need to check the test package version that you needed from your project pubspec.yaml. And then goto mockito github to check the commit history (https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/commits/master/pubspec.yaml) to see whether which version is using the test package fits your project.

Comment: @CbL ok thanks! so from github, I couldn't find version 4.1.4, but for 4.1.2, they have `dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  build_test: ^1.1.0
  build_web_compilers: '>=1.0.0 <3.0.0'
  pedantic: '>=1.3.0 <1.9.1'
  test: ^1.5.1.` With my pubspec file, it has  these dev_dependencies:  `flutter_test: 
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^4.1.4`. So do I add all the mockito dev_dependencies to mine? Or do I just do something like change `flutter_test: ` to `flutter_test: ^1.5.1`?

Comment: @JohnBradens I think you can try `flutter_test:`  to `flutter_test: ^1.5.1` first, since this is the only package being complained

Comment: @CbL So it looks like `flutter_test: ^1.5.1`
    `sdk: flutter`, and I tried commenting out `sdk: flutter` and leaving it in, and I get errors each way :/ what do I do?